# Showing the holomorphic function contains at least one zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D\in \mathbb{C}$ be an open set and $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. Suppose we fix $z_0\in D$ then we know that there is a local Taylor's expansion in $B(z_0,r)$ for some $r>0.$ (the corresponding closed ball also lies in $D$.)

The question asks if $|f(z_0)|<\min_{z\in\partial B(z_0,r)}|f(z)|$ then it must contain a zero in the aforementioned open ball.

I thought to prove by contradiction by saying that $\frac{1}{f}$ must be holomorphic on this open ball then I could also deduce the inequality $$|\frac{1}{f(z_0)}|<\max_{z\in\partial B(z_0,r)}|\frac{1}{f(z)}|.$$

However I am not too sure how to proceed further. This kind of reminds me of Rouches Theorem but I am not sure how to apply it.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the inequality backward! Your idea of using contradiction is great, now google the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: OP is using MMP to $\frac 1  f$ so there is no mistake in the stated inequality.

Comment: My answer is correct, there is a mistake in the inequality since he is starting from $f(z_0) < \min f(z)$.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum Modulus Principle shows that if there is no zero then $\frac 1 {|f(z_0)|} \leq \max_{|z-z_0| \leq r} \frac 1 {|f(z)|}=\max_{|z-z_0| = r} \frac 1 {|f(z)|}$ But this is equivalent $|f(z_0| \geq \min \{|f(z)|: |z|= r\}$. This is a contradiction and hence $f$ must have  a zero.